# Cannot use Pandas pct_change with date

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame:

```
                 date  value
0 2017-11-30 13:58:57    901
1 2017-11-30 13:59:41    905
2 2017-11-30 13:59:41    925
```

That was generated by:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame.from_items( [('date', ['2017-11-30 13:58:57', '2017-11-30 13:59:41', '2017-11-30 13:59:41']),("value", [901, 905, 925])])
df['date'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
```

I want to calculate the percentage change between two consecutive rows,  but when I use:

```
df.pct_change()
```

I get the error:

```
ufunc true_divide cannot use operands with types dtype('<M8[ns]') and dtype('<M8[ns]')
```

How do I make it ignore the date column?

Comment: Does `pct_change` have any meaning for datetime columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do I make it ignore the date column?

Here's a solution with `select_dtypes` that should generalise to any dataframe by ignoring non-numeric columns -

```
df.select_dtypes(include=['number']).pct_change()

      value
0       NaN
1  0.004440
2  0.022099
```

Comment: This works. But suppose I want to save the resultant pct_change dataframe in df_1, how to add the Date column to this df_1?

Answer (score 1):

I’d try specifying the value column.

```
df[‘pctcng’]=df[‘value’].pct_change()
```