# Dataframe pct_change(), best way to ignore or evade the TypeError for columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Given the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df_ = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1.79, 1, 0, 0, 0, pd.Timestamp('2018-01-01 00:00:07'), 0.0,
        1.3075932699341621, 0.14, 0.20999999999999996, 2.58],
       [1.83, 1, 0, 0, 0, pd.Timestamp('2018-01-01 00:00:07'), 1.05,
        1.3075932699341621, 0.14, 0.20999999999999996, 2.58],
       [1.83, 1, 0, 0, 0, pd.Timestamp('2018-01-01 00:00:07'),
        2.0833333333333335, 1.3075932699341621, 0.14,
        0.20999999999999996, 2.58],
       [1.85, 1, 0, 0, 0, pd.Timestamp('2018-01-01 00:00:07'), 3.1,
        1.3075932699341621, 0.14, 0.20999999999999996, 2.58],
       [1.85, 1, 0, 0, 0, pd.Timestamp('2018-01-01 00:00:07'),
        4.133333333333334, 1.3075932699341621, 0.14, 0.20999999999999996,
        2.58]], dtype=object))

df_.pct_change()
```

An error appears on the last line:

> TypeError: cannot perform **truediv** with this index type: DatetimeIndex

- Reading the error, it seems the problem is with the timestamp column, it is not possible to operate with it.
- Do I need to drop the date column to execute the function? Having multiple datetime columns, which would be a fast way to execute the `pct_change()` function ignoring those datetimes (or any not accepted dtype)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47793356/cannot-use-pandas-pct-change-with-date

Comment: @JohnSloper yep that's exactly what I wanted. I did not find the answer searching, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First if necessary convert columns to floats and then seelct only numeric columns by [`DataFrame.select_dtypes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html):

```
def f(x):
    try:
        return x.astype(float)
    except:
        return x

df_ = df_.apply(f)

print (df_.select_dtypes(np.number).pct_change())
         0    1   2   3   4         6    7    8    9    10
0       NaN  NaN NaN NaN NaN       NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1  0.022346  0.0 NaN NaN NaN       inf  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
2  0.000000  0.0 NaN NaN NaN  0.984127  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
3  0.010929  0.0 NaN NaN NaN  0.488000  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
4  0.000000  0.0 NaN NaN NaN  0.333333  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
```